# quip - cannot create own app

Tags: quip, liveapps

As stated in the title, I cannot create my app on quip. I followed the steps as documented here (https://quip.com/dev/liveapps) Problems as follows:

1. `create-quip-app my-app` doesn't create my-app folder, instead, always creates live-app
2. The generated file is different from the document. Here is the file I get.

   ```
   live-app
       |- assets
       |    |- icons
       |    |    |- thumbnail.svg
       |    |    |- toolbar.svg
       |    |- styles.css
       |- jest.config.js
       |- manifest.json
       |- package.json
       |- src
       |   |- components
       |   |      |- main.test.tsx
       |   |      |- main.tsx
       |   |- menus.ts
       |   |- model
       |   |    |- root.test.ts
       |   |    |- root.ts
       |   |- root.tsx
       |- tsconfig.json
       |- webpack.config.json
   ```
3. In order to run `npm run build`, I need to run `npm install` in the live-app folder, which is not stated in the document
4. After `npm install` and `npm run build`, `app.js` file is created under `/dist`. There is no `app.ele` file created.

```
    live-app
        |- assets
        |    |- icons
        |    |    |- thumbnail.svg
        |    |    |- toolbar.svg
        |    |- styles.css
        |- dist
        |    |- app.js
          .
          .
          .
```

5. When I upload `app.js` file on quip, I get this error: `The element package is malformed.`

### Spec

- Mac, macOS Catalina Version 10.15.2
- npm@6.14.8
- Node.js v14.13.1
- create-quip-app, I tried with these versions (0.0.45, 1.0.0-alpha.4, 1.0.0-alpha.41, 1.0.0-alpha.46, 0.1.1)
- webpack 4.44.2

---

According to here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-quip-app), `create-quip-app` is depricated now and suggested to use `quip-cli` but `quip-cli` still has issue and can't do `qlp login`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the new templates no longer running `create-quip-app pack` as part of the npm `build` script.

You've correctly noticed that we're in the process of a transition, and the docs are slightly out of date. I'd recommend either adding `&& create-quip-app pack` to your `npm run build` command, or using `create-quip-app@0.0.45` to generate and build your apps for now, which will use the old template.

The Quip team will be releasing a large update to the docs soon, which should help clarify the process going forward.